# How to check equality of more than 2 collections using SequenceEqual LINQ method?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have the following collections:

```
string[] names1 = { "Kareem", "Mohammed", "Borai" };
string[] names2 = { "Kareem", "Mohammed", "Borai" };
string[] names3 = { "Kareem", "Mohammed", "Borai" };
```

And I looking for code like this:

```
bool isEqual = names1.SequenceEqual(names2).SequenceEqual(names3);
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are more collections to check put them into another collection and use `All` method

```
bool isEqual = new [] { names2, names3, ... }.All(names1.SequenceEqual);
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using simple `&&` operator :

```
bool isEqual = names1.SequenceEqual(names2) && names1.SequenceEqual(names3);
```